# PHP cURL with Proxy ( Not SOCKS5 )

Tags: php, curl, proxy, vpn, php-curl

I had working code that used my VPN (NordVPN) credentials through their SOCKS5 protocol.

Recently, they have dropped support for SOCKS5 so I have to use their other protocols, however I am unable to get any to work.

All of their available protocols can be seen here

```
https://nordvpn.com/servers/tools/

- IKEv2/IPSec
- OpenVPN
- Wireguard
- HTTP Proxy (SSL)
```

Here is my code, attempting to use their "HTTP Proxy (SSL)" protocol

```
$cookie_file = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120); // in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "443");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "au643.nordvpn.com");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyUser . ":" . $proxyPass); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The error I get is

```
curl_exec(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource in ...
```

I don't really care what protocol it is, just need it to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

After facing the same issue, I have worked out a solution

```
$PROXY_HOST = "xxx.xxxxxx.com";
$PROXY_PORT = "89";
$PROXY_USER = "yourproxyusername";
$PROXY_PASS = "yourproxypassword";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "$PROXY_USER:$PROXY_PASS");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "https://$PROXY_HOST:$PROXY_PORT");


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response= curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch); 
echo $error;
echo $response;
curl_close($ch);
```

One thing to note is that for NordVPN you have to use the port 89 for HTTP Proxy (SSL) and the username and password is not your account username and password, but your proxy specific credentials that you can find on your account page.

Also dont quote me on this, but I think you need to use PHP 7.3+ for this to work.

Comment: I did try this and still i get an error : Failed to connect to dublin.ie.socks.nordhold.net port 89: Connection timed out

Comment: Sounds like you are using a sock5 IP and not a SSL one. That's why it's failing for you @androidbash

Comment: according with NordVPN you can use ONLY socks5.. no http anymore https://nordvpn.com/blog/removing-http-proxies/

Answer (score 0):

we can use it with protonvpn or vpnbook ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32781246)